# JSlint: Unexpected string concatenation error

Tags: jquery, error-handling, compiler-errors, jslint

Getting Unexpected string concatenation error,

All my functionality is working good, but it showing me Unexpected string concatenation error

```
$this.find('.content > .component:gt(' + (limit - 1) + ')').hide();
```

I used the below, but functionality is not working,

```
$this.find(`.content > .component:${limit - 1}`).hide();
```

Comment: `.component:N` is not a valid selector. Are you looking for `:eq()` to select an element by its index?

Comment: yes, I am bringing the index count by using inner class .component

Comment: Whats wrong  in my question, String concatenation is bringing many errors in different scenarios, if you get this issues in beginning of your career you can come to know about my situation...

Answer (score 0):

We have to use template literals instead of string concatenation.

```
$this.find(`.content > .component:gt(' ${limit- 1} ')`).hide();
```

back quote "`" should be use and (' ${} ') should use when you call a value in your function

For reference follow this,
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-template

Comment: Thank you @Lanka Patrudu